# VMWare ESXi 5 - How to clone Windows 2008 SBS

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, boot, clone

I am running two Windows 2008 Server on a VMware ESXi 5 Server (VMware vSphere 5 Essentials Kit). There are two different ESXi hosts within my VMware datacenter environment. Let us call them esxserver1 and esxserver2. 
Both of my Windows 2008 Servers are currently running on esxserver1 and I would like to move both Windows Servers to esxserver2 due to performance reasons (esxserver2 is much more powerful).

I actually expected that I can just clone both Windows VMs using vCenter but unfortunately the VM clones did not work after they were cloned successfully from esxserver1 to esxserver2.

Both Windows 2008 Server were stuck with some strange krnl error messages like the following ones:

ntkrnlpa.exe missing or corrupt

After I ran a repair from Windows Installation DVD a both machines came up with a quite similar error:

ntoskrnl.exe missing or corrupt

I really wonder what I did wrong. Do I have to consider something else when cloning Windows 2008 servers from one esxserver to another?

Comment: If you want to move them then move them. There are a number of ways to do this: migrate, copy, etc. and a number of tools available to do this: WinSCP, Veeam FastSCP, Trilead VMExplorer, etc.

Comment: Please clarify what hardware esx1 and esx2 have.If they are using different CPU family this can cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to clone them. Just right-click in VMWare Manager and choose "Migrate". From there you can move them. Note: The machines will have to be powered off to do this.